# How to secure embeded videos in a epub ebook?

Tags: epub, epub3

I've been asked to create an education ebook which contains 200 videos for a total size of 25 Go (!).

Although it is my first ebook creation, I can't imagine to embed so many videos in the epub file, and so, I plan to only use external videos.
Since the making of these videos requested a lot of work (and personnal funds), the teacher want to secure the videos and avoid the videos to be stolen and made publicly visible on other sites.

How can I include external videos in an epub ebook in a safe manner ?

Thanks in advance for any tips !

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: there is no way to 100% "protect" a resource embedded in an EPUB file, if the user has access to the EPUB file itself.

Long answer: unless you are also creating the reading application intended to be used for consuming those EPUB files and thus you can prevent the user from "reaching" the actual EPUB file, there is no 100% secure way of preventing a user from extracting a resource (the video, in your case) from an EPUB file.

Traditionally, to prevent "oversharing" of the EPUB file itself or "unauthorized extraction" of some assets (images, audios, videos) two main techniques are used: DRM or per-purchase watermarking. If you apply a DRM (i.e., the Adobe DRM), there are programs to remove it with just a click. The per-user watermarking route seems difficult for videos, I do not think any watermark provider has a tool to insert hidden user info inside videos embedded in EPUB files.

Another possibility consists in NOT embedding the video inside the EPUB file, and just link to it or to declare it as a "remote resource" (see http://www.idpf.org/epub/301/spec/epub-publications.html#sec-resource-locations ). But again, this does not prevent a malicious user from downloading the video from the URL you need to specify in the EPUB file.

Probably the best solution consists in showing some information (like "(c) Name_of_the_author, 2016") in a corner of the video. Again, very determined pirates might crop that text off, but at least discourage the "casual oversharers".

Answer (score 1):

As with every ePub response, this depends entirely on the distribution channels they require. If they plan to distribute the ePub files directly, and the ePub files are ePub3 / HTML5 compatible, I would suggest this:

host the videos on a site that provides custom domain-level-access to the videos (like Vimeo: https://help.vimeo.com/hc/en-us/articles/224817847-Privacy-settings-overview), then have the video live in an iFrame to your site and require users to authenticate to that iFrame before the videos will play.

This will prevent people from sharing the videos by simply copying and pasting a URL, which will give you client peace of mind. But there will ALWAYS be the possibility of an authenticated user downloading/saving the video and then re-posting it in a public place. But you will always have that possibility regardless of security: because someone can always do a screen record and audio capture for any video they can see.

Best of luck,
-Alex